# XCode - Indexing failed in one file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This issue is not a major issue but has certainly made the process consume more time. When I build my application, indexing fails in one and only one file (**.m** file if it matters).

There is not intelligence, no color on ***global variables*** and most of the code except for important keywords are black in color. Since there is no intelligence, whenever I need to make changes, I have to see other files for doing the changes.

Comment: you could try : 1) cleaning the project and close it. 2) then open the Organizer and remove all derived data 3) then delete the project in that list. Once you'll reopen the project Xcode will reindex everything.

Comment: Where in organizer will I find derived data?

Comment: Organizer -> Projects -> ..., you'll see the project list on the left, select yours and you can see two buttons on the top of the view (Derived Data and Snapshots).

Comment: Did what you suggested. Still not indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my question. Actually a localized file of that file was being created in **en.proj** folder, where indexing failed. So, I just copied that file into project main folder and deleted it from **en.proj** folder. It works fine now. I can see everything indexed.

Answer (score 3):

this happend for me when the file was not included in the target.

Method 1:
- Go to your project (the very first item in the project list) (`cmd-1`)
- select your target
- open tab Build `Phases`
- add your `.m` file in `Compile Sources`

Method 2:
- select your `.m` file
- show Utilities Pane (the one on the right side)
- first tab: `show the file inspector` (`cmd-option-1`)
- check the target in `Target Membership`

Comment: you could reproduce your problem case for testing and see if this help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I follow when I face such a situation :

1. Clean the project, in Xcode menu Product -> Clean
2. Close the project
3. Open Organizer and go to Projects tab, select the project
4. Remove all derived data (the buttons are on the main view : Derived data and Snapshots)
5. Remove the project from the list on the left (select it and press backspace)
6. Finally close Xcode, launch it again and reopen the project

These steps will make Xcode rebuild the index for the whole project.

Comment: Still no Vince. Might be some other issue.

Comment: I posted my own answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

If indexing fails, try cleaning the product (or entire build folder). If that doesn't help, close Xcode, remove the `DerivedData` folder (you can find the location in the preferences "Locations" tab), and start Xcode again.

The indexing process will then try to re-index your files.

Comment: I posted my own answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Considering the normal `Clean` or `Delete Derived Data` solutions haven't worked, my next steps would be:

1. Copy the contents of the .m to the clipboard.
2. Delete the .m from your project (including sending the physical file to Trash)
3. `Delete Derived Data`
4. Try to compile the project (I know it will generate errors most likely, but let it do this).
5. Create a new .m file and paste the code back in.
6. Compile and run the project.
7. `Delete Derived Data` again to force a reindex.
8. Close XCode, reopen it.

Now hopefully it should be indexed. If this still doesn't work, try renaming that class (the .h and .m), see if it indexes, then rename it back again.

Comment: I posted my own answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Product > Clean (XCode 4).
This can happen sometimes, it's annoying. If you get desperate, try creating a new project in a different location and copying the source files over.

Comment: I posted my own answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for "GCC_INCREASE_PRECOMPILED_HEADER_SHARING" in your project build settings
2. Change 'increase sharing for precompiled header' from NO to YES

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Editor -> Syntax coloring, and change it to objective c. It might do the trick.

Comment: It was not me who down voted Bani. But the answer you gave is not the right way to get to the solution. What you are suggesting appears to be bluffing ourselves although we know this is wrong. Changing color won't make intelligence work. And frankly speaking, it is absolutely wrong.

Comment: I know it's not the right way to do it, but I don't know where a question of bluffing comes up here. And that's why I had mentioned that, "it might do the trick", it might get the syntax colors for classes. And i don't think anything is it is right to judge if it is absolutely wrong or right, this solution has worked for me in a project where i had the same problem and no solution worked. A solution not working for you does not give you the privilege to mark it wrong, when it can be of use to someone else.

Comment: @BaniUppal - [voting down](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) is a privilege here for anyone who have at least 125 reputation.